Is there an excel function to assign a binary result to a predefine data cell?
Sorry for the title, I know it might be pretty wide and not so much informative. I am facing a problem regarding the analysis of a data set. The participants of my experiments were randomly assigned to different conditions and some stimuli were randomly assigned to them. I would like to analyze the data (without looking each line one by one) but I don't know how to do because of the randomly assigned stimuli. Can you please tell me how to do it ?
The table (please, don't give attention to the yellow cells):

As you can see, each stimulus (x_.jpeg) is associated with a binary answer. I would like to reproduce it in the right side of the table in order to have a detail of the answer of each participant facing a specific stimulus.

If you do not know how to analyze the data, then how can we help?  This is a site to help with code that is not performing correctly not help create models to analyze data.

Alright, I note it for the future. I am sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks Scott

You can use the MATCH and INDEX functions to look up the values for each of the different jpeg file names.
I made a smaller version of your dataset and used this function to pull the answer for a particular .jpeg name:
IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$F2,1,MATCH(G1&"_.jpeg",$A2:$F2,0)+1),"")

sample dataset
The IFERROR function is used so that if a particular filename is not found in the row of data, instead of a reference error, the field is left blank. Then you can filter your data on participants who had got number 17, for example.

Judging by the image you need MATCH+1 instead MATCH-1.

@P.b You're right. I've edited it with the correction.
